# is it possible to add background position to img /asp:image tag

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, image

I am working on optimizing page load

First option i went for is base64 conversion

I have 18 small images to be loaded in home page
Since base64 is 1.3x the actual image size i went for image sprites

After spriting the images, i am able to use it for replacing `background-image` ,  `background-position` for div, but i am not able to use sprited image for replacing `img` and `asp:image` tags. I need to have them as `<asp:image>` as there are some code behind functions attached to it

Comment: Have you profiled your page to see what bottlenecks it has?

Comment: the backgroun-image and background-position attributes didnt apply when i loaded the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add transparent images for all `asp:Image` controls. They will render as HTML images. And then you should make sure that you add the correct css class with the appropriate sprite for each.

See an example at http://jsfiddle.net/9wo2mL32. Also, make sure you add width and height to the class (or to the `asp:Image` control):

```
<asp:Image ID="imgImage" runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" ...
```

Comment: How can i stretch the background image?

Comment: @vignesh You can use the `background-size` css property. See updated example at http://jsfiddle.net/9wo2mL32/1/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use sprites on images, the key points is to add height/width and an empty/transparent image `1pixel x 1pixel` on the `src` so can load something and show something as image tag, because with out valid src browsers may show error img, or nothing

The rendered results can be like:

```
<img class="rgoto" src="spacer.gif" height="9" width="8" >
```

and style :

```
img.rgoto {
background: url(sprite.gif) no-repeat -230px -20px;
height: 9px;
width: 8px;
}
```

Comment: How can i stretch the background image?